# Working IntelliJ Scala Plugin Tutorial?

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea

I'm having some trouble getting the scala plugin to work with IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1 Community Edition on Mac OSX 10.6.8. I'm following these [instructions](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Getting+Started+with+IntelliJ+IDEA+Scala+Plugin) but whenever I try to run the simple HelloWorld application, I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7533 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 10 CE.app/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javaws.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/management-agent.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/plugin.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/alt-rt.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/alt-string.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/charsets.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/ui.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/apple_provider.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Users/A482930/IdeaProjects/ScalaPractice/out/production/ScalaPractice:/Users/A482930/scala/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/A482930/scala/lib/scala-swing.jar:/Users/A482930/scala/lib/scala-dbc.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 10 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked the module settings and the compiler library seems to be set up correctly. The version of scala I'm using is the 2.9.0.1 with the IzPack Installer. I've tried both the IDEA plugin listed under available plugins as well as the July 5 2011 nightly [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+IDEA+X).

Rather then helping me troubleshoot my specific issue, does anyone know of a step by step tutorial that actually works without issues for a configuration similar to mine? I'm ok with using older versions of scala and even IDEA as long as they work.

Comment: Mind you, any help debugging this specific issue would be greatly appreciated as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you still need help with this, but I just ran a simple example with Scala 2.9.0.1 and it worked. I've been having tons of issues with the plugin though, so I guess it would help to know the exact steps you followed.

In my case, I did this:

1. Created Project
2. Added Scala Facet in the Project Wizard and added the Scala libs as a global lib (there are a few issues with this, but it should work here)
3. Create your HelloWorld example
4. Create a new Scala Compilation Server Runner. Add the Classpath of your project
5. Run the project

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine created this some months ago, after having some issues getting started:
 https://github.com/runeflobakk/sbt-idea-scalatest

Guess it is more SBT focused, but maybe you can find some use in it anyway?